# Symfony: multiple entity manager (sonata)

Tags: symfony, entity, sonata-admin, entitymanager

I have a hard problem that wants an answear. I am working with Symfony and I installed Sonata to manage the admin area. After I completed to do that, my prompt line give me this error:

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrFCL.png)

This is my code:

```
parameters:

services:       
    app.security.user_login_form_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\UserLoginFormAuthenticator
        autowire: true

    app.security.admin_login_form_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator
        autowire: true
```

Please, help me.

Comment: Do you have multiple EntityManger defined in the config file(s) of your project?

Comment: I think yes. After I instaled Sonata, the prompt line said me the error in the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrFCL.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autowiring feature is handy, but it has a limitations.

As you say, you have multiple instances of entity manager. So, Symfony doesn't know which of them should be injected into your services. If a service definition were available to change, you would set the [`autowiring_types`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/autowiring.html#dealing-with-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-type) parameter to specify a default implementation of dependency. But usualy entity manager services are defined by DoctrineBundle and you can not configure it directly. (As I know, Doctrine configuration doesn't provide options to set up that.)

So, the easiest way is to manually specify the entity manager: just pass a entity manager service ID (doctrine.orm.XXX_entity_manager) to constructor arguments of your services.

```
services:       
    app.security.user_login_form_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\UserLoginFormAuthenticator
        arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.XXX_entity_manager' ]

    app.security.admin_login_form_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\AdminLoginFormAuthenticator
        arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.YYY_entity_manager' ]
```

Obviously, if services have other dependendecies, you also need to specify them.